# prepend not working in symfony task

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

For symfony task we need to call at the end of execution say end.php

code :

```
if($a)
     die(); // end.php should not be called
else
{
    //end.php should be automatically called.
}
```

I tried using

```
  auto_append_file = /usr/local/scripts/config/end.php
```

but its not working in symfony task

Answer (score 0):

What is your end.php script suppose to do ? What about using exec() ?

something like

```
$cmd = "php /path/to/end.php";
if (strtolower(PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX) === 'dll')
   $cmd .= ' &';
else // Linux/UNIX/OS X
   $cmd = '/usr/local/bin/'.$cmd.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &';
exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the note of [auto_append_file in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file):

> **Note**: If the script is terminated with exit(), auto-append will not occur.

A symfony task always ends with an exit() (zero if ok, returned task's status code if not)